# Encoding email with Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3

Tags: email, zend-framework, encoding, zend-mail

I try get email with Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3 but the chars come with encoding strange.
Example

```
Endere=E7o
Paran=C3=A1
```

*shold be*

```
Endereço
Paraná
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not give much explanation or code ...
I can propose this:

When you set your email, use utf-8:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
```

Comment: OK, but how do you create the mail? You don't use Zend_Mail? Give us your code.